# Override @JsonIgnore annotation for some controllers. Jackson. Spring

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson, kotlin

I need to serialize photos field only for direct requests to the entity. But when user make request to all MediaHolders objects, serialize only short information with photoSize.

I'm using Kotlin, Jackson, Spring and Hibernate. 
I've tried:

- @JsonView on contoller. Doesn't work. JsonView doesn't override @JsonIgnore behavior. Or I'll need to annotate all fields in base PersonalDomainObject class and all controllers, which is not suitable for me.
- Custom JsonFilter, but the same, it doesn't see ignore fields. And I can't add different Filters on different Controllers.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I think it's very common task in optimization. Thank you very much for any suggestion!

```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties("createdAt", "updatedAt", "owner", "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler")
    open class MediaHolder : PersonalDomainObject() {

        @OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE), mappedBy = "mediaHolder")
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
        var photos:MutableList<Photo> = mutableListOf()

        val photosSize: Int
            get() = photos.size
}
```